# How to use two arrays to display select options

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two fields in my database called `temp_files` & `real_files`.

`temp_file = means new name of the file`
`real_file = means old name of the file`

Want to know how i store file names in database?

e.g

`temp_file = TSGTSabc.zip, GSHSHfile.jpg, HSNabcd.rar`  //new file name are typically random
`real_file = abc.zip, file.jpg, abcd.rar`

Now I'm trying to show it as like shown below

```
<select name="file">
    <option value="temp_file">real_file</option>   // value of temp_file field from database
    <option value="temp_file">real_file</option>   // value of real_file field from databse
</select>
```

I'm using explode and then using foreach loop

```
$og_file = explode(', ',$query['temp_file']);
$file = explode(', ',$query['real_file']);

foreach($og_file as $temp_file){

echo '<option value="$temp_file">real_file</option>';
}
```

But i have no idea how to show data of other array in this foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
$query['temp_file'] = "a, b, c";
$query['real_file'] = "1, 2, 3";

$og_file = explode(', ',$query['temp_file']);
$file = explode(', ',$query['real_file']);
$i = 0;
foreach($og_file as $temp_file){
  echo '<option value="'.$temp_file.'">'.$file[$i].'</option>';
  $i++;
}
```

But Ensure both arrays should have same no. of elements otherwise you may get error  or notices.

Answer (score 1):

If your arrays have same length

1. you can add `$index` variable for your foreach loop:

   ```
   $array1 = array("a1", "b1", "c1");
   $array2 = array("a2", "b2", "c2");

   foreach($array1 as $index => $value1) {
       $value2 = $array2[$index];
       echo $value1 . " - " . $value2;
   }
   ```
2. You can use `array_combine` function (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php)

   ```
   $array1 = array("a1", "b1", "c1");
   $array2 = array("a2", "b2", "c2");

   $merged = array_combine($array1, $array2);
   foreach($merged as $value2 => $value1) {
       echo $value1 . " - " . $value2;
   }
   ```